# Mac OS application (dmg) - storage of properties

Tags: c#, node.js, macos, properties, dmg

I am pretty new to MacOS and building applications on it and I have a question:

When I build a dmg and run it, is there any usual approach to store some properties? I want to access those properties each time I start my application, so they need to remain in the storage. (I want to store them at the first run of the dmg file and then keep them.)
I also want to store some properties which shall be deleted each time after running the application.

My application is based on nodejs. I have another (for Windows, written in C#) where I use the Properties to store some variables (which I want to remain for each run). (e.g. Properties.Settings.Default.variable)

I'd like to know if there is an often used approach for MacOS applications too?

Thanks for help in advance!

Greetings

Comment: I read a lot and I think I found out that plist-files can be used to store persisent properties.